# Template Haskell type quoting problems

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

The TemplateHaskell quoting documents two quotes (`''`) as the way to get the Name of a type:

```
> ''String
GHC.Base.String
```

This works fine for this type (name). However, I can't find a way to make it work nice for e.g. `Maybe String`:

```
> ''Maybe String -- interprets String as a data constructor
> ''Maybe ''String -- wants to apply ''String to the Name type
```

I know I can workaround via using `[t| Maybe String |]`, but this is then in the Q monad, and requires type changes, and I think is not type-checked at the respective moment, only when spliced in.

I can also work around by first defining a type alias, `type MaybeString = Maybe String`, and then using `''MaybeString`, but this is also cumbersome.

Any way to directly get what I want simply via the `''` quotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`''` is used to quote *names*, not types. `Maybe` is a name, `Maybe String` is not. It is therefore not too surprising that you have to give your type a name by defining a type alias, before you can quote that name.

`[t| |]` on the other hand, quotes *types*. Note the difference here.

```
Prelude> :t ''String
''String :: Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Name
Prelude> :t [t| String |]
[t| String |]
  :: Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Q Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Type
```

So I'm afraid you cannot use `''` for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, then I guess I have to either use quasiquoting or find another solution as to not have to add [t| |] everywhere…

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
ConT ''Maybe `AppT` ConT ''String
```

Comment: Indeed, that works, but it is at cross with my purpose of trying to find a simple way to allow (other people) to write such a construct. Thanks in any case!

Comment: We have this predicament at a few places in Yesod. I think the result I came up with was just parsing a string, which works our fairly well most of the time. __Edit__ I'm guessing for your use case the [t|...|] would probably be better anyway, never mind.

Comment: Yep, I thought about parsing the string too (I like how one declares the database in persistent, for example). However, it wouldn't help much in my case anyway. Maybe I'll find a better solution later, for now I can manage with the [t|…|] :)