# Generate a function using Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Is it possible to define a function using Template Haskell? For example

```
convertStringToValue :: String -> Int
convertStringToValue "three" = 3
convertStringToValue "four" = 4
```

I also have a `Map [Char] Int`.

```
fromList [("five",5),("six",6)]
```

How can I add functions

```
convertStringToValue "six" = 6
convertStringToValue "five" = 5
```

at compile time using Template Haskell and the `Map`? It appears quite silly to use Template Haskell for this purpose but I would like to know nevertheless.

Comment: I can understand wanting an example to learn TH with, but this would be easier to do with `lookup' key = fromJust . Map.lookup key`

Comment: @bheklilr I am quite aware of that but I just wanted to know if it could be done using TH just out of curiosity.

Comment: Another possibility that isn't TH is to just write a normal Haskell function that saves Haskell source code to another file, and then compile that file as normal. Just throwing that out there...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid That too is an option for solving the problem without using TH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using two files:

a "maker" file: **`Maker.hs`**:

```
module Maker where

{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH

maker items = do
    x <- newName "x"
    lamE [varP x] (caseE (varE x) (map (\(a,b) -> match (litP $ stringL a) (normalB $ litE $ integerL b) []) items))
```

and the main file: **`Main.hs`**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Maker

function = $(maker [("five",5),("six",6)])
```

In that case `function` will be of the type `[Char] -> Int` and will be compiled as:

```
\x -> case x of
    "five" -> 5
    "six" -> 6
```

It is thus as if you would have written:

```
function = \x -> case x of
    "five" -> 5
    "six" -> 6
```

yourself. Evidently that's not going to pay off for two or three cases, but as you have written in the question yourself, when you want to use thousands of cases, or a list of items generated by list comprehension, this starts to pay off.

## Making template Haskell yourself

This section aims to briefly describe how to write template Haskell yourself. This tutorial is not *"a complete introduction to..."*: there are other techniques to do this.

In order to write template Haskell, you can first try a few expressions, and then try to *generalize* them using `map`, `fold`, etc.

### Analyze the AST tree

First you better take a look on how Haskell would parse a certain expression itself. You can do this with `runQ` and brackets [`[| ... |]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7489277/67579) with `...` the expression you wish to analyze. So for instance:

```
$ ghci -XTemplateHaskell
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m Language.Haskell.TH
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> runQ [| \x -> case x of "five" -> 5; "six" -> 6 |]
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pretty-1.1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package template-haskell ... linking ... done.
LamE [VarP x_0] (CaseE (VarE x_0) [Match (LitP (StringL "five")) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 5))) [],Match (LitP (StringL "six")) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 6))) []])
```

The AST is thus:

```
LamE [VarP x_0] (CaseE (VarE x_0) [Match (LitP (StringL "five")) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 5))) [],Match (LitP (StringL "six")) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 6))) []])
```

So now we have *derived* the *Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)* from that expression. A hint is to make the expressions generic enough. For instance use multiple cases in the `case` block, since using a single case doesn't tell you how you should add a second one to your expression. Now we wish to create such abstract syntax tree ourselves.

### Create variable names

A first aspect is the variables, like `VarP x_0` and `VarE x_0`. You cannot simply *copy-paste* them. Here `x_0` is a name. In order to make sure you don't use a name that already exists, you can use `newName`.  Now you can construct the following expression to fully replicate it:

```
maker = do
    x <- newName "x"
    return $ LamE [VarP x] (CaseE (VarE x) [Match (LitP (StringL "five")) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 5))) [],Match (LitP (StringL "six")) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 6))) []])
```

### Generalize the function

Evidently we are not interested in constructing a fixed abstract syntax tree, otherwise we could have written it ourselves. Now the point is that you introduce one or more variables, and reason about that variables. For every tuple `("five",5)`, etc. we introduce a `Match` statement:

```
Match (LitP (StringL "five")) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 5))) []
```

Now we can easily generalize this with `\(a,b)`:

```
\(a,b) -> Match (LitP (StringL a)) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL b))) []
```

and then use the `map` to iterate over all items:

```
map (\(a,b) -> Match (LitP (StringL a)) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL b))) []) items
```

with `items` the list of tuples for which we wish to generate cases. Now we're done:

```
maker items = do
    x <- newName "x"
    return $ LamE [VarP x] (CaseE (VarE x) (map (\(a,b) -> Match (LitP (StringL a)) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL b))) []) items))
```

Now you can simply omit the `return` because the library has lowercase variants for all these items. You can furthermore try to "*cleanup*" the code a little bit (like for instance `(NormalB (LitE (IntegerL b)))` to `(NormalB $ LitE $ IntegerL b)`, etc.); for instance using `hlint`.

```
maker items = do
    x <- newName "x"
    lamE [varP x] (caseE (varE x) (map (\(a,b) -> match (litP $ stringL a) (normalB $ litE $ integerL b) []) items))
```

The *maker* here is some kind of function that makes/constructs the function.

### Careful for *infinite lists*

Be aware that the compiler will evaluate what it is in between the dollar brackets `$()`. If you for instance would use an infinite list:

```
function = $(maker [(show i,i)|i<-[1..]]) -- Don't do this!
```

This will keep allocating memory for the abstract syntax tree and eventually run out of memory. The compiler does *not* expand an AST at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
import Language.Haskell.TH

generateDict :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> Q [Dec]
generateDict fname sns = do
    let clauses = map clause sns
    return $ [FunD (mkName fname) clauses]
        where clause (s,n) =
                Clause [LitP . IntegerL $ toInteger  n]
                       (NormalB . LitE $ StringL s )
                       []
```

And then

```
generateDict "myDict" $ zip (words "One Two Tree Four") [1..]

myDict 1 -- => "One"
```